# Add entity with InheritanceType.JOINED to native query

Tags: hibernate

I am struggling to get native queries to work with `InheritanceType.JOINED`. From the Hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch13.html#d5e3844) I have found:

> ## 13.1.6. Handling inheritance
>
> Native SQL queries which query for entities that are mapped as part of an inheritance must include all properties for the baseclass and all its subclasses.

Using the following two entities:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_super")
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id"})
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class MySuper {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;

}
```

And:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_sub_a")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class MySubA extends MySuper {

    @Column(name = "x")
    private int x;

}
```

When I try to create a native query using:

```java
Object actual = session
    .createNativeQuery("SELECT {s.*} FROM my_super {s} LEFT JOIN my_sub_a {a} USING (id)")
    .addEntity("s", MySuper.class)
    .getSingleResult();
```

It translates to the query:

```
SELECT s.id as id1_1_0_, s_1_.x as x1_0_0_, case when s_1_.id is not null then 1 when s.id is not null then 0 end as clazz_0_ FROM my_super s LEFT JOIN my_sub_a  a  USING (id)
```

And then fails with:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "S_1_.X" not found; SQL statement:
```

So we observe the alias injection doing its work, figuring out that it may need the `x` column of `my_sub_a` as well. It is however unable to figure out the alias for `my_sub_a`. How should my code be modified so that this alias is connected properly as well?

My code is available at https://gist.github.com/JWGmeligMeyling/51e8a305f3c268eda473511e202f76e8 for easy reproduction of my issue.

*(I am aware that this query can easily be expressed in JPQL or HQL as well, and can even be achieved using the `EntityManager` and `Session` API's. I do however want to use this in a more complex query, that I simplified to all details required for this question).*

Comment: You should probably either replace `{a}` with `a`, or add another `.addEntity("a", MySubA.class)`, since it's messing with aliases. But this is just a try

Comment: What I get from the documentation you've quoted is that you need to include a's properties in the select so maybe `SELECT {s.*}, {a.*} [...]`. Also I think you should try `.addEntity("a", MySubA.class)` without the super class since it would probably fail to instantiate an abstract class.

Comment: Nope, thats not it, if I use `.addEntity("a", MySubA.class)`, Hibernate assumes it needs to fetch two distinct entities, rather than figuring out the properties belong to the same entity. That I use an unreferenced `{a}` in my query is actually a copy-paste error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems related to the underlying database dialect in use, in other words to some "exotic" query parts. The behavior you described is replicable with your provided query but with some tiny tweeks it's running without errors - depending on the dialect you want to use.

In your example you use the H2 database, but I assume that's not your production dialect, right? I also tried it with PostgresSQL database (in version 9.5).

With the origin query, the behavior is the same on H2 and PostgreSQL. But if you remove the curly braces from your columns and aliases (which seem like some [ODBC escape sequences](http://coldfusion.sys-con.com/node/41682)) and change the [USING clause](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqljusing.html) to an explicit `ON a.id = s.id` condition the query is executable without any exception.

To verify the behavior I created some tests with different queries using either the Hibernate Session or the EntityManager, because after taking a look at your linked example code I got somehow confused by the mixed up usage of the [Hibernate Session interface](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html) and [EntityManager methods like createNativeQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery-java.lang.String-). In case of doubt I gave a try for both.
 I used the same entities and more or less the same configuration and test code like you did in your example but within a [Spring Boot environment](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/), only for convenience purposes. For switching between the databases I used [Spring Boot Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html), just activate / uncomment the `@ActiveProfiles("postgres")` part if you have configurations for both databases in place.

Here are the tests, I hope that does help a little:

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
//@ActiveProfiles("postgres") // activate for PostgreSQL tests
public class InheritanceDemoApplicationTests {

    private static final String QUERY = "SELECT {s.*} FROM my_super {s} LEFT JOIN my_sub_a {a} USING (id)";
    private static final String QUERY_WITHOUT_ODBC_ESCAPES = "SELECT s.* FROM my_super s LEFT JOIN my_sub_a a USING (id)";
    private static final String QUERY_WITHOUT_USING_KEYWORD = "SELECT {s.*} FROM my_super {s} LEFT JOIN my_sub_a {a} ON a.id = s.id";
    private static final String QUERY_WITHOUT_ODBC_ESCAPES_AND_WITHOUT_USING_KEYWORD = "SELECT s.* FROM my_super s LEFT JOIN my_sub_a a ON a.id = s.id";

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Test
    public void sessionQuery() {
        validateQueryViaSession(QUERY);
    }

    @Test
    public void entityManagerQuery() {
        validateQueryViaEntityManager(QUERY);
    }

    @Test // works for PostgreSQL
    public void sessionQueryWithoutOdbc() {
        validateQueryViaSession(QUERY_WITHOUT_ODBC_ESCAPES);
    }

    @Test // works for PostgreSQL
    public void entityManagerQueryWithoutOdbc() {
        validateQueryViaEntityManager(QUERY_WITHOUT_ODBC_ESCAPES);
    }

    @Test
    public void sessionQueryWithoutUsing() {
        validateQueryViaSession(QUERY_WITHOUT_USING_KEYWORD);
    }

    @Test // works for H2
    public void entityManagerQueryWithoutUsing() {
        validateQueryViaEntityManager(QUERY_WITHOUT_USING_KEYWORD);
    }

    @Test // works for H2 & PostgreSQL
    public void sessionQueryWithoutOdbcAndWithoutUsing() {
        validateQueryViaSession(QUERY_WITHOUT_ODBC_ESCAPES_AND_WITHOUT_USING_KEYWORD);
    }

    @Test // works for H2 & PostgreSQL
    public void entityManagerQueryWithoutOdbcAndWithoutUsing() {
        validateQueryViaEntityManager(QUERY_WITHOUT_ODBC_ESCAPES_AND_WITHOUT_USING_KEYWORD);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private void validateQueryViaSession(final String queryString) {
        final MySubA match = persistMySubA();
        List result = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).createSQLQuery(queryString).addEntity("s", MySuper.class)
                .list();
        assertThat(result.iterator().next()).isEqualToComparingFieldByField(match);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private void validateQueryViaEntityManager(final String queryString) {
        final MySubA match = persistMySubA();
        List result = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString, MySuper.class).getResultList();
        assertThat(result.iterator().next()).isEqualToComparingFieldByField(match);
    }

    private MySubA persistMySubA() {
        final MySubA mySubA = new MySubA();
        mySubA.setX(1);
        entityManager.persist(mySubA);
        entityManager.flush();
        return mySubA;
    }

}
```

Comment: Interesting catch! The curly braces origin from the Hibernate example, I figured it was required for hibernate to detect the fields but apparently it only made things worse. Now that I think of it too, it makes sense Hibernate was unaware of the unionon construction (I wouldnt think it would use anything besides the projection but it seems to process the entire query then). Anyways, thanks a lot for investigating this!

Comment: You are welcome. :) To satisfy entity creation just all fields have to be part of the projection, curly braces are not needed here. You can also offer a dedicated constructor and leverage 'select new ...' https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html